# How can i count all likes from another tabel?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I already made it to the point that my SQL reutrns all posts from tbl_posts when they have at least one like. BUt now i am wondering how i can get it work so it returns all posts even when they have no likes. The likes are stored in tbl_posts_likes via foreign keys (post_id, user_id as columns in tbl_posts_likes). My SQL looks like this at the moment:

```
SELECT tbl_posts.*,tbl_users.name,COUNT(tbl_posts_likes.user_id) AS likes
FROM tbl_posts 
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_posts.user_id = tbl_users.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_friends fr WHERE fr.friend_id = '1') AS fr ON tbl_posts.user_id = fr.user_id 
RIGHT JOIN tbl_posts_likes ON tbl_posts_likes.post_id = tbl_posts.id
WHERE tbl_posts.user_id = '1' OR tbl_posts.user_id = fr.user_id 
ORDER BY tbl_posts.created_at DESC
```

It would be nice if you can help me out because i am searching since days to get a working SQL set up :/

Greetings from Germany!

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with your database example? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Yeah for sure: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200ba/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200ba/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to group by tbl_posts.id to get the results per post.
If you dont do this all results are merged into one row.

a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200ba/20) with the results per post, if it has no likes the result is 0.

```
SELECT tbl_posts.*,tbl_users.name,COUNT(tbl_posts_likes.user_id) AS likes
FROM tbl_posts 
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_posts.user_id = tbl_users.id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_posts_likes 
ON tbl_posts.id = tbl_posts_likes.post_id
group by tbl_posts.id
```

A nice way to find solutions for problems like this:

Simplify the problem by first just getting the posts with a count of likes only. later add the other joins but first focus on getting the most basic result.

Comment: Works :3 Thanks for your help i already had something like this but at least it works now